# MySQL error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql, swing

This is my register page:

[image]

Registration was working before adding Email checker functionality.
This function for check  did someone used this email on database.

This is my code:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    sqlConn = DriverManager.getConnection(connect, username, password);
    if (check_email(u.getEmail())) {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        sqlConn = DriverManager.getConnection(connect, username, password);
        String query = "insert into users_table (Name_surname,E_mail,Age,Profession,Student,Password)"
                            + " values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        pst = sqlConn.prepareStatement(query);

        pst.setString(1, u.getName_surname());
        pst.setString(2, u.getEmail());
        pst.setInt(3, u.getAge());
        pst.setString(4, u.getProffesion());
        pst.setString(5, u.getStudent());
        pst.setString(6, u.getPassword());
        pst.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You signed up");

    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have already account");
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Register.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}


public boolean check_email(String username) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    sqlConn = DriverManager.getConnection(connect, username, password);
    boolean e_mail = true;
    String query = "Select * from users.users_table where E_mail = ?";
    try {
        pst = sqlConn.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1, j_register_mail.getText());
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            e_mail = false;
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Register.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return e_mail;
```

This is my database:

[image]

[image]

I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at JFrame.Proje.Register.check_email(Register.java:462)
at JFrame.Proje.Register.register_btActionPerformed(Register.java:430)
at JFrame.Proje.Register.access$400(Register.java:30)
at JFrame.Proje.Register$5.actionPerformed(Register.java:334)
```

Comment: I Googled for **mysql access denied for user** and found this: [SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://howtodoinjava.com/sql/sqlexception-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-after-re-installation-of-mysql-server/)

Answer (score 1):

Within the method `check_email` you are connecting to the database using `username` and `password`.

But you do have a local variable/parameter with the same name `username` which prevents `getConnection` from seeing/using the correct global `username`.

And why create a new DB-connection within the `check_email`-method instead of passing the connection as a parameter to the method or using a class-variable for the connection?